# date more than 12 giving SqlDateTime overflow exception in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form through which i want to store some data in database. For the date in mm-dd-yyyy format when i enter any date greater than 12 I am getting exception `SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.` Can you tell me why?

Comment: when I am putting date greater than 12 such as 12-13-2013(13th December 2013) The value sent to the sql server becomes 01-01-0001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you are confused between date and month. Default US notation use MM/DD/YYYY pattern. It seems you're using DD/MM/YYYY pattern.

You can switch to desired pattern or change default culture in your web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="en-US" />
    ...

  </system.web>
```

Change en-US to what you really need.